# How to select randomly from a list of string-array

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I have a list of string arrays:

```
<string-array name="chapter_1">
      <item>......</item>
      .           
      .
      .
      .
</string-array>

<string-array name="chapter_2">
      <item>......</item>
      .           
      .
      .
      .
</string-array>
```

and so on.
I have got a random int chapter_no.

I have a string:

```
String chapter_name = "chapter_" + chapter_no;
```

Now, I want to access string array corresponding to the chapter_no.

I know that I can't do like this:

> String[] chapter =
>   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapter_name);

How can I access the string arrays randomly? Please help me.

Comment: Do you want a random String Array or a random String from a known chapter?

Comment: First I want to get string array and then a string from chapter. Let me say I want a random string ( item ) from chapter.

Comment: Do u want random string(item) from any specific chapter or from all?

Comment: @learner can 't u iterate through the element and find the element you are looking for?

Comment: @Apurvak From a specific chapter.

Comment: @nafas How can I iterate, if I don't have array-string

Comment: @learner if you are looking to iterate through them I can show you how? so that's what you want right?

Comment: I don't want to.. My question is clear I think

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then @Moinkhan 's answer should help you achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try as follows

**UPDATE**

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(chapter_name, "array",this.getPackageName()); 
String[] chapter = getResources().getStringArray(id);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Your answer is working well. thank you for the answer. I can't find any documentation for the topic. Please suggest me one.

Comment: @learner i am also new to this i referred following http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 2):

To get Random String from chapter_array ..

```
String[] chapter = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapter_name);

String randomString = chapter[new Random(chapter.length).nextInt()];
```

**[Updated]**

```
        String[] data;

        //first of all give all resources to arrays
        int[] arrays = {R.string.chapter_1, R.string.chapter_2};

        //then we are fetching any one string array resources randomly
        int chapter_no = arrays[new Random(arrays.length).nextInt()];

        //From above we got any one random resource string..So we fetch all string items from that resource into data array
        data = getResources().getStringArray(chapter_no);

        //Now from that data array we fetch any one random string.
        String randomString = data[new Random(data.length).nextInt()];
```

**[updated]**

```
    String[] data;
    int[] arrays = {R.array.chapter_1, R.array.chapter_2};
    int chapter_no = arrays[new Random().nextInt(arrays.length-1)];
    data = getResources().getStringArray(chapter_no);
    String randomString = data[new Random().nextInt(data.length-1)];
    Toast.makeText(this, randomString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I want to make sure one thing ,...
the chapter_name is available to you or not ....???

Comment: chapter_name is  a variable, not a constant.. Please go through question. It is not working at all and I tried it..

Comment: Yeah, I got a solution like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139015/randomly-select-a-string-from-strings-xml-in-android                 But I don't want to make an array because there are 100 chapters.

Comment: But if you are talking about 100 chapters then you should have to Sqlite ...
which is batter option for you..

Comment: I know that. but I am using string-array. And also using array instead of string works..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80179/discussion-between-moinkhan-and-learner).

Comment: Oh sry you should have to use  { R.array.chapter_1 } instead of { R.string.chapter_1 }

Comment: **Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0xc
            at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:468)**

Comment: Here is my final edited answer ..
I have implement it my side ..
And Working prefectly...
I have make the sily mistake with Random class. So check it let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of all those array ids, and then pick one of them in that array.

```
int[] arrays = {R.array.chapter_1,....};
```

Randomly pick one among these array.

```
 Random random = new Random();
 int chapter_no = arrays[random.nextInt(arrays.length)];
```

Comment: As described in the given question? Can't i have a better solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139015/randomly-select-a-string-from-strings-xml-in-android

Comment: but you have an array of string-array.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have 2 strings and you want to get them randomly you can do it like this:

```
Random random = new Random();

int chapter_no = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
String chapter_name = "chapter_" + chapter_no;
```

This `Random` function that I put above will get values until number 2.

I expect it helps to you!

Comment: I have more than 2 string arrays and corresponding chapter no.

Comment: @learner and do you know exactly the number of string arrays that you have there?

Comment: @learner Then you can change the number inside the nextInt witht the number of string-arrays that you have (the total). `random.nextInt(total) + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do this :

```
String[] chapter = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapter_1);
String[] chapter2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapter_2);
Random rand=new Random();
int randomNo=rand.nextInt();


ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(chapter));
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(chapter2));
String [] concatedArgs = temp.toArray(new String[chapter.length+chapter2.length]);
String item=concatedArgs[randomNo];
```

Comment: I don't  want this solution man. This will select from chapter_2. I want to get from any chapter.

Comment: please don't delete the previous answer.. some times other users get confused. and write edit on the top of the answer.. I will try your solution also.